# Calculating Card permutation based on creation guidelines

Tags: algorithm, math, permutation

I have the following rule set for creating trading cards similar to pokemon.
This is similar to character creation you might see in a game like fallout. You start out with base stats, and can spend a number of points proportional to the rarity(stars) of the card you are creating.

For example, all cards would start as a base card with 10hp, and 1 move that does 10dmg and requires 1 energy. A 1 star card woul start with 10 points to spend. You could spend 4 of your 10 starting points to raise hp to 50, 3 points to raise dmg to 40 and 3 points to add a status effect to the move. The natural energy requirement of a move is dmg/40 rounded up. Raising the cost of a move gives you additional points to spend but is capped at 5 energies per move. Each card cannot have more than 3 moves.

COSTS:
Stars can be 1-4

Starting points: 10 X Stars, give or take 1 X Stars

+10 hp: 1 point

+10 move dmg: 1 point

Raise Energy Cost: refund 3 Points

Lower Energy Cost: 4 points

Add Status Effect:  3 points

add Additional move: 1 point

Base Energy cost =  Move Dmg  / 40 Rounded Up. Maximum of 5

Base Card:

10 hp
1 move: 10dmg 1 energy requirement

UPDATE: A move's energy cost CAN be reduced to zero, and the energy cost can never be more than 5.

Given the above formula, what formula would I use to calculate how many permutations this will create. All the 1 star permutations + 2 stars + 3 stars + 4 stars.

Ultimately, I'm going to be creating a program that will export each possible permutation into a CSV file and make a checklist.

Comment: What are all those units you mention: hp, dmg, star, X star?

Comment: hit points, damage a move does, rarity represented by 1-4 stars,  X star just meant 1 times number of stars.

Comment: Is the base energy cost limit of 5 also applicable to raising the energy cost? Meaning that if a move costs 5 energy can you raise its cost further? Because if there is no limit to how often you can raise the energy cost you have access to an unlimited amount of points and as such to an unlimited number of different cards. You could, for example, just take any card and then raise the energy cost to increase the hit points by 30. This could be repeated forever resulting in an infinite amount of different cards.

Comment: no, 5 is the hard cap. a move can never cost more than 5 energy

Comment: Must a move cost energy or can you reduce the energy cost to 0?

Comment: it can be reduced to 0

Comment: You spend a lot of time explaining the system, but it's not entirely clear which part of this you're having trouble with or what kind of help you want from us. Where's your question?

Comment: If you're looking to print out all possible permutations, that should be fairly simple to do with a modified version of [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) (although you need to be smart about how you do it to avoid duplicates, or just store all generated permutations and check whether you've already generated it).